# Cannot convert to base class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm building a wpf form with a combobox and a datagrid. The combobox is bound to a collection of the model base class moWeek. The selected item is bound to a derrived class of  called wm like this `SelectedItem="{Binding Week, Mode=TwoWay}"`, whereas  is just property of the type `vm` in the Viewmodel class.

Now when I select the a value from the combobox I get a System.NotSupportedException called TypeConverter cannot convert model.moWeek.

I figured I need some kind of converter from moWeek to vmWeek, but I don't know where and how to put it. How would I do this?

Here is the code:

Model week class:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Model
{
    public class moWeek
    {

        public moWeek()
        {

        }

        private int id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel week class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Model;
using ViewModel.Lists;

namespace ViewModel.Planning
{
    public class vmWeek  : moWeek
    {
        private ProjectList projects;

        public ProjectList Projects
        {
            get { return projects; }
            set { projects = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Projects")); }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using tegViewModel.Auswahllisten;


namespace tegViewModel.Planning
{
    public class vmPlanning : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public vmPlanning()
        {
            Weeks = new alWeeks(); //Collection of moWeek

        }

        public alWeeks Weeks { get; set; }

        private vmWeek week;

        public vmWeek Week
        {
            get { return Week; }
            set { Week = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Week")); }
        }


        private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a class that implements interface `IValueConverter`

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(moWeek), typeof(vmWeek))]
class MoWeekToVmWeekConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var moweek = value as moWeek;
        vmWeek result = //Do your conversion;
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (moWeek) value;
    }
}
```

After that you can declare an instance of the class in resources.

```
<local:MoWeekToVmWeekConverter x:Key="MoWeekConverter"></local:MoWeekToVmWeekConverter>
```

Once you declared converter you can use it in binding.

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Week, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MoWeekConverter}}"></ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. Btw, I found another solution, by changing the type of Weeks to a collection of vmWeek and put an implicit converter into the alWeeks collection.

Comment: I wondered why you could not do that :) and I decided to consider that as a prerequisites.